# Percona MySQL 5.7 to 8.0

Tags: mysql-5.7, percona

I wondered if anyone has successfully upgraded percona 5.7 to 8.0 with a fully populated database. All the articles I've read suggest it is possible but I've tried twice in a test environment and whilst the upgrade happens, it stalls during the service start and never really gives a true indication why.

It's a large multi database server with over 100dbs at over 150gb.

I'd like to get the process nailed because when it comes to live, the servers are in a replication cluster. I've read to start with the slaves first which is fine, but even that suggests I should be able to upgrade with data.

When checking the tables are okay for upgrade they all return OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to migrate MySQL 5.7 to 8.0 with data and rollback plan

How to check the compatibility with MySQL 8.

1. Install MySQL Shell (*Reference: [Installing MySQL Shell on Linux](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-install-linux-quick.html)*)
2. Use MySQL Shell Upgrade Checker Utility

   ```
    mysqlsh -- util check-for-server-upgrade { --user=root --host=localhost --port=3306 } --config-path=/etc/my.cnf
   ```

   This will produce an output similar to the following:

   > ```
   > 1) Usage of old temporal type
   >   No issues found
   >
   > 2) Usage of db objects with names conflicting with reserved keywords in 8.0
   >   No issues found
   >
   > 3) Usage of utf8mb3 charset
   >   No issues found
   >
   > 4) Table names in the mysql schema conflicting with new tables in 8.0
   >   No issues found
   >
   > 5) Partitioned tables using engines with non native partitioning
   >   No issues found
   >
   > 6) Foreign key constraint names longer than 64 characters
   >   No issues found
   >
   > 7) Usage of obsolete MAXDB sql_mode flag
   >   No issues found
   >
   > 8) Usage of obsolete sql_mode flags
   >   No issues found
   >
   > 9) ENUM/SET column definitions containing elements longer than 255 characters
   >   No issues found
   >
   > 10) Usage of partitioned tables in shared tablespaces
   >   No issues found
   >
   > 11) Circular directory references in tablespace data file paths
   >   No issues found
   >
   > 12) Usage of removed functions
   >   No issues found
   >
   > 13) Usage of removed GROUP BY ASC/DESC syntax
   >   No issues found
   >
   > 14) Removed system variables for error logging to the system log configuration
   >   To run this check requires full path to MySQL server configuration file to be specified at 'configPath' key of options dictionary
   >   More information:
   >     https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-13.html#mysqld-8-0-13-logging
   >
   > 15) Removed system variables
   >   To run this check requires full path to MySQL server configuration file to be specified at 'configPath' key of options dictionary
   >   More information:
   >     https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/added-deprecated-removed.html#optvars-removed
   >
   > 16) System variables with new default values
   >   To run this check requires full path to MySQL server configuration file to be specified at 'configPath' key of options dictionary
   >   More information:
   >     https://mysqlserverteam.com/new-defaults-in-mysql-8-0/
   >
   > 17) Schema inconsistencies resulting from file removal or corruption
   >   No issues found
   >
   > 18) Issues reported by 'check table x for upgrade' command
   >   No issues found
   >
   > 19) New default authentication plugin considerations
   >   Warning: The new default authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' offers
   >     more secure password hashing than previously used 'mysql_native_password'
   >     (and consequent improved client connection authentication). However, it also
   >     has compatibility implications that may affect existing MySQL installations.
   >     If your MySQL installation must serve pre-8.0 clients and you encounter
   >     compatibility issues after upgrading, the simplest way to address those
   >     issues is to reconfigure the server to revert to the previous default
   >     authentication plugin (mysql_native_password). For example, use these lines
   >     in the server option file:
   >
   >     [mysqld]
   >     default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
   >
   >     However, the setting should be viewed as temporary, not as a long term or
   >     permanent solution, because it causes new accounts created with the setting
   >     in effect to forego the improved authentication security.
   >     If you are using replication please take time to understand how the
   >     authentication plugin changes may impact you.
   >   More information:
   >     https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html#upgrade-caching-sha2-password-compatibility-issues
   >     https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html#upgrade-caching-sha2-password-replication
   >
   > Errors:   0
   > Warnings: 1
   > Notices:  0
   > ```

It provides the significant changes required for you to upgrade to MySQL 8.0 and you can then apply these changes to MySQL 5.7. before you upgrade to 8.0.

Then run the MySQL Shell Upgrade Checker Utility again and see whether the issues have been fixed.

Keep the same character set and collation as in your 5.7 version to avoid other possible conflicts and issues.

Comment: While this is a very good answer, it relates to MySQL . The author is asking about Percona. Is your answer valid for Percona as well? [Percona Server for MySQL Feature Comparison](https://docs.percona.com/percona-server/8.0/feature_comparison.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for your generous support

Comment: It will be same of percona @john